React - Warning: Cannot update a component while rendering a different component in React
I encountered the following warning in my react project.

Warning: Cannot update a component (App) while rendering a different
component (TattooForm).

Here’s a brief overview of the workflow for my TattooForm props.

I have a parent component App that passes state to a child component TattooForm via props.
The TattooForm component has an image upload feature where the user selects a body part, and uploads an image. I updated the state in the parent component (App) to pass it again to another child component.

Parent App.jsx
function App() {
    const [uploadedImages, setUploadedImages] = useState({});

    const handleUploadedImages = (newImages) => {
        setUploadedImages(newImages);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <TattooForm handleUploadedImages={handleUploadedImages} />
            <Experience uploadedImages={uploadedImages}/>
        </div>
    );
}

Child Tattoo.jsx
const TattooForm = ({ handleUploadedImages }) => {
    const [selectedBodyPart, setSelectedBodyPart] = useState("");

    const handleImageChange = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
            const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            setSelectedBodyPart(imageUrl); // Local state update

            // Here I am calling the parent function to update the parent state
            handleUploadedImages({ [selectedBodyPart]: imageUrl });
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={handleImageChange} />
        </div>
    );
};


Are you able to create a reproducible example? Can't reproduce it with the code you've provided.

attempted to use useEffect in the TattooForm component to handle the state update?

I don't see any overt issue in the code you have shared here other than that selectedBodyPart won't have updated to the value you want for handleUploadedImages({ [selectedBodyPart]: imageUrl }); in handleImageChange because React state updates are not immediately processed and can not change the value in scope anyway. Use handleUploadedImages({ imageUrl }); instead and remove the local selectedBodyPart unless you have need for it elsewhere in the component.

For the issue you are asking about, please [edit] to include a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. If possible, see if you can create a running CodeSandbox demo that reproduces the error that readers can inspect live.

FWIW I've copy/pasted your code into a running sandbox and cannot reproduce the issue. The issue is elsewhere. Is this a complete [mcve] you have shared?

const TattooForm = ({ handleUploadedImages, imageUrl }) => {
    const [pendingImages, setPendingImages] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (pendingImages) {
           handleUploadedImages(pendingImages); // I Passed updates to parent after render
         }
     }, [pendingImages, handleUploadedImages]);

    const onTattooUpload = (event) => {
        if (!selectedBodyPart) {
            alert("Please select a body part first.");
            return;
         }
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
            const tempImageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        // Update the state and call the parent handler inside an event handler
               setUploadedImages((prevImages) => {
                   const newImages = { ...prevImages, [selectedBodyPart]: 
                         tempImageUrl };
                   setPendingImages(newImages); // Store pending updates to be passed to parent later
                   return newImages;
               });
        } return;
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={handleImageChange} />
        </div>
    );
};


Code-only answers are not very helpful or useful. Adding an explanation of the issue/problem and where/how/why the code resolves the problem is desired.
